# Is there any method for jasper reports to support Khmer language?

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports

I tried to generate a jasper report that has khmer characters in it but while generating the PDF , the letters get absurdly changed. Is there any method or configurations through which Khmer language can be supported in Jasper reports?

Comment: You are tagging this question as an iText question, but JasperReports is a tool that isn't endorsed by iText Group, JasperReports uses a version of iText that dates from 2009. Support for Asian languages other than Chinese, Japanese and Korean was introduced in 2016 with the release of iText 7 and the pdfCalligraph add-on; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861083 for more info. Maybe you should consider using another templating solution, for instance: [iText DITO](http://dito.online/); See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815311 for more info.

Comment: What JasperReports version are you using?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie , thanks for the response , when I searched through the internet for this issue , it seemed to be somehow related to iText and thanks for the suggesting a possible solution .I'll check that and update .

Comment: @dada67 , I'm using jasper reports version 5.6.0.

Comment: Try upgrading to JasperReports 6.2.0 or newer.  It might help with Khmer texts (as long as you're using a Khmer font extension).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this post related to Jasper with Khmer Unicode: http://ask.osify.com/qa/868

> Starting with JasperReports 6.2.0, support for complex/Indic scripts
>   in PDF (by means of AWT text layout) has been added. It can be seen in
>   the demo/samples/unicode sample, which contains a Khmer text rendered
>   with a Google Noto font.
>   See comment of [Jasper reports - Cambodian / Khmer and Laotian Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750736/jasper-reports-cambodian-khmer-and-laotian-language/43868037?noredirect=1#comment74791921_43868037)

I already experience myself, latest jasper report version can support Khmer but won't work properly when it comes with latin character there too, we need to edit font on this.